# Cambiar tamaño del terminal con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, exe

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en Python que muestra el numero de infectados de Coronavirus según el país que escribas. El problema, es que no puedo cambiar el tamaño de la consola con la que se abre el programa. He intentado con estas tres lineas de código diferentes:

```
os.system('mode con: cols=10 lines=42')
subprocess.Popen(["mode", "con:", "cols=25", "lines=80"])
cmd = 'mode 50,20'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Todas esas manera son válidas, ¿te da algún error?

Comment: Sí, en el caso de los os.system, me salta "mode" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo. Y en subprocess, simplemente no cambia nada.

Comment: Lo primero sería probar el comando directamente en la consola. ¿Con que S.O. trabajas?

Comment: Prueba con `subprocess.Popen('cmd /c "mode 50,20"')`. Estoy suponiendo que estás en *Windows*. Un saludo.

Comment: @tecnobillo Ya probé con `subprocess.Popen('cmd /c "mode 50,20"')`, pero me sigue saltando la advertencia.

Comment: @CandidMoe Estoy haciendo esta aplicación en Windows 10

Comment: Si abres un cmd y ejecutas `mode con: cols=50 lines=20` sin resultado, podría ser un problema con las variables de entorno. Para más información consulta esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413860/cmd-no-reconoce-ning%c3%ban-comando-en-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Llego un poco tarde para la respuesta, a mi me ha funiconado eso:

```
from os import system    
system('mode con: cols=200 lines=49')
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Es importante explicar en una respuesta porque la solución que indicamos es apropiada, ya que la misma no solo ayuda a quien pregunta, sino a otros muchos. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].

Comment: Usando from os import system system('mode con: cols=200 lines=49') Se logra cambiar el tamaño pero te quita la posibilidad de hacer scroll en ella... Se puede aumentar el tamaño de buffer desde python? Gracias!