# CMD no reconoce ningún comando en Windows 10

Tags: cmd, windows10, registro-windows

Como dice el título al lanzar el comando `attrib` en el CMD para cambiar las propiedades de un archivo el comando no es reconocido aunque en el pasado lo usé sin problemas.

Recientemente estuve haciendo modificaciones en la variable Path del sistema (no del usuario) y algunas fueron eliminadas, pienso que podría haber una conexión.

Si escribo `attrib` en `C:\Windows\System32\` obtengo una lista de todos los archivos dll de la carpeta de esta manera:

```
A                    C:\Windows\System32\xwtpdui.dll
A                    C:\Windows\System32\xwtpw32.dll
A                    C:\Windows\System32\X_80.contrast-black.png
```

Pero si lo hago desde `C:\Users` obtengo:

```
"attrib" no es reconocido como un comando interno o externo,
 un programa ejecutable o un file batch.
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado ejecutarlo desde la carpeta `X:\windows\system32`? (Donde `X` es la letra de la unidad de sistema)

Comment: verifica esta documentación: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23538880/4717133

Comment: y esta otra: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607681/batch-file-attrib-r-var1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los comandos que intentas ejecutar en la terminal se buscan en una serie de carpetas configuradas en la variable de entorno llamada `PATH`.

Si has modificado esa variable (o la has borrado), entonces los típicos programas de línea de comandos no serán encontrados a menos que especifiques la ruta completa hacia ellos.

Puedes verificar si en tu variable de entorno está o no la carpeta `C:\Windows\System32`, entrando en una terminal y ejecutando la orden `PATH`. Si no está, de ahí te viene el problema.

Puedes restaurar esa variable de entorno ejecutando el comando "Propiedades del sistema" desde el menú de Inicio, y allí en el botón "Variables de entorno". Busca la variable llamada PATH entre las variables de sistema. Si no la encuentras, de ahí viene el problema. Créala y dale como mínimo los dos valores siguientes:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32
%SystemRoot%
```